# .exe file compiled with GCC(9.2.0) on VSCode is not running when executed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, exe

I have searched Stack Oveflow for a question similar to mine and found one case, but it was totally different from mine. So, here is my question.

I am using Visual Studio Code that has been linked to the MigGW GCC Compiler (v.9.2.0) to compile and execute c and c++ programs. So far, all my executables created using MinGW are running without a hitch.
Except a few programs.
I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. I am not performing any operations without first initializing the variables and there is no ambiguity. Still, the compilation completes successfully, but the .exe file refuses to work.
I tried running it through `cmd` and the VSCode `integrated terminal` the exe files still won't run.

(I use a `tasks` file in VSCode to create the `exe` file)

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    int choice, err;
    char ch;
    cout << "\nHello\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\nChoose:\n";
        cout << "1) Call by value.\n";
        cout << "2) Call by reference (addresses).\n";
        cout << "3) Call by reference (pointers).\n";
        cout << "4) Exit.\n";
        cin >> choice;
        try
        {
            if(isalpha(choice))
                throw choice;
            else
            {
                cout << "Enter n1: ";
                cin >> n1;
                cout << "Enter n2: ";
                cin >> n2;

                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        swap(n1, n2);           //call by value
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        swap(&n1, &n2);         //call by reference (addresses)
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //swap();               //call by reference (pointers)
                        cout << "\nProper\n";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout << "\nWrong option.\n";
                        break;
                }
                cout << "After swapping: \n";
                cout << "n1 = " << n1 << "\tn2 = " << n2 << endl;
            }
        }
        catch(int err)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter a valid option:\n";
        }
        cout << "Press Y to run again.\n";
        cin >> ch;
    }while(ch =='y' || ch == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me:

1. why the `exe` doesn't run?
2. How can I avoid such problems in future? Do I write my code in a certain way or what else can I do?

(this is not the only code where I'm encountering this issue.)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"? Do you get an error? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: How does `swap(n1, n2);` even compile? Are you sure that your `swap()` function is called, or eventually `std::swap()` comes into play?

Comment: @AlanBirtles when I type in the `exe` file name and press enter, there is literally no output. No error, nothing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, the `swap(n1,n2)` does compile successfully and execute. I ran the exact same code above in a online IDE. It works flawlessly.

Comment: Are you sure your code is compiling? Have you checked the modification date of the executable? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes @AlanBirtles I have. And this is not the issue with just this piece of code. They compile successfully. It's getting on my nerves now.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have not. The program executes properly on all online IDE's but I'll still debug it and let you know.

Comment: @Capt_Steel Add another `cout` statement into your swap, and check if it prints please. Also try removing `using namespace std;`, and explicitely qualifying stuff from tghe c++ standard library by prefixing with `std::`.

Comment: its fixed. Seems to be a machine related issue. I asked a few friends to run it the same way and it works in theirs.

Comment: Comment by  πάντα ῥεῖ  is very important because std:: has a swap macro, never use any `using namespace XX`, this should be made a linter warning